# Sims 3: Mad scientist looking for a new job

Tags: the-sims-3

If a mad scientist in Sims 3 gets a new job, can you still perform experiments on random objects?

Comment: That's a good question. I'm inclined to think the answer is yes, but I can't say for certain.

Comment: Oh come on, the title to this question would be *so* much better without Sims 3: prefixing it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After finally becoming a mad scientist I promptly quit, and I was still able to perform experiments on my unsuspecting household items.

Answer (score 1):

you could get into science career.
when you get to level 10 you get some sort of Beam you can make akward things with. For example you could point it towards a refridgenator and maybe the refridgenator starts to float

when you have the amitions expansion pack you could also get inventor because when you reach level 3 or 4 you get a detonator whcih you can sue to block things up.
You can blow up your neightbors bed